# CSS - textbox and checkbox next to each other inside td

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a textbox and checkbox next to each other, my problem is the checkbox goes to the next line:

```
<td><div class='allDropdown'><input type='text' class='vendorDropdown' /> <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' /></div></td>
```

I am trying to get them next to each other.

Here is my CSS:

```
.allDropdown {
    width: 100%;
}

.allDropdown input[type=text]  {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.allDropdown input[type=checkbox] {
    float: left;
}
```

I have a very long table and I am also using bootstrap, when I try to decrease the size of the textbox, the td just gets smaller and the checkbox goes to the second line

Comment: Objects and/or styling that is parent to the HTML code you have provided is causing the issue, need to supply more code. If you put your code in a HTML document it is fine:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.allDropdown {
    width: 100%;
}

.allDropdown input[type=text]  {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.allDropdown input[type=checkbox] {
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='allDropdown'><input type='text' class='vendorDropdown' /> <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' /></div>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

you can position your text box as absolute so it will stick in any side you want

try this..

```
.allDropdown {
    width: 100%;
}

.allDropdown input[type=text]  {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.allDropdown input[type=checkbox] {
    position:absolute;
    right:<x>px;
    top  :<x>px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually that code seems about right. It's not rendering the two inputs in different lines. Can you show more code please? There might be some bootstrap styling going on there. On the other hand, instead of floating them, you should always try to change the way the box is being displayed instead of taking it ouf of the frame with the float; have you tried with display:inline-block for both?. Does the table have any styling going on that might be adjusting the size of the TDs?